# Invalid token on email confirmation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken, email-verification

I am getting random error of Invalid token when some users want to verify their emails in my application. It works for majority of the people but once in a while, someone runs into this error of invalid token while trying to verify the email.

Here is my code that generates and sends the token

```
 var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(agent).ConfigureAwait(false);
                code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = agent.Id, code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

Another issue I am also facing which I think might be related to this one is that my application also generates an error with antiforgery token though it still submits the forms without any issues.
It always throws this error whenever a page with Antiforgery token is visited. Such pages as login, signup or any page at all that contains a form with Antiforgery token on it
The error it always returns is

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery|An exception was thrown while deserializing the token. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AntiforgeryValidationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
> ---> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {1c4319c7-f7f0-4ae2-a1f1-fc9e7124d65b} was not found in the key ring.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.UnprotectCore(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean allowOperationsOnRevokedKeys, UnprotectStatus& status)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.DangerousUnprotect(Byte[] protectedData, Boolean ignoreRevocationErrors, Boolean& requiresMigration, Boolean& wasRevoked)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Unprotect(Byte[] protectedData)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgeryTokenSerializer.Deserialize(String serializedToken)

My application is an ASP.NEt core 3.1, running on a Windows shared hosting

Thank you

Comment: It is a slightly contentious issue - but I'd argue that it is pointless to check an antiforgery token on any unauthenticated page (e.g. login).

Comment: @mjwills The login page requires the AntiForgeryToken to verify that the page is submitted from the website.
However, The Antiforgery token is not the main question here. The email validation token is the main issue I wish to resolve